# $k*x^2+y^2=z^2$; Elementary question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Sorry for the inconvenience, I have a very elementary question.
In the equation $kx^2+y^2=z^2$,what are the conditions for $k$, where $k,x,y,z$ are integers and not primes and $k$ is not a perfect square.(At least I know if $k$ is a perfect square, the equation is Diophantine).

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are $(x,y,z)$  integers?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question. They are Integers.

Answer (score 2):

For any integer $k$, there are infinitely many solutions of the form, for all integers $a$,

$$x = \left|2a\right| \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$y = \left|a^2 - k\right| \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

$$z = \left|a^2 + k\right| \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

This is because, for all real $b$ you have $\left|b\right|^2 = b^2$ (I'm using absolute values to more easily handle dealing with primes), so you also have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
kx^2 + y^2 & = k(2a)^2 + (a^2 - k)^2 \\
& = 4ka^2 + a^4 - 2ka^2 + k^2 \\
& = a^4 + 2ka^2 + k^2 \\
& = (a^2 + k)^2 \\
& = z^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

For all $\left|a\right| \gt 1$, you have $x$ not being a prime. Also, for any integer $k$, there are an infinite number of $a$ for which both $y$ and $z$ are not prime either, e.g., where $a$ and $k$ have the same parity so $2$ divides both $y$ and $z$.

Comment: Nice find. Incidentally, for $k=2$, it works also if $y=2a^2-1$ and $z=2a^2+1$, a case independent of your general identity. Furthermore, your answer can be extended as: $$x= 2ab$$ $$y=a^2-k\cdot b^2$$ $$z=a^2+k\cdot b^2$$ +1 though :)

Comment: @MrPie Thanks for the compliment and your suggestion about another set of general values for $k = 2$. There will usually be additional cases for any specific values of $k$, such as your suggestion, and there are also other somewhat different general equations than what I proposed, in addition to the one you proposed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $(x,y,z,k) \in \mathbb Z$,

$z^2 \equiv 0 $ or $1\pmod 4$

and since  $y^2 \equiv 0 $ or $1 \pmod  4$

$kx^2 \not\equiv 2 $$ \pmod 4$

Now, as $x^2 \equiv 0 $ or $1 \pmod 4$,

$k \not\equiv 2 \pmod 4$.

And that was just one condition. You can do $n^2 \equiv i,j,k,... \pmod l $ and get the conditions for $k$ in different modulo $l$.

Comment: I would like to dig deeper and get more than modular restictions. What is the Equation called in general?

Comment: Which equation do you mean?

Comment: $k*x^2+y^2=z^2$, the one in the post

Comment: I do not know what it is called in general.

Comment: $k=2$ is a counterexample. Let $k=2$ then, for all $a$, it follows $x=2a$, $y=2a^2-1$ and $z=2a^2+1$.